# make aborting because zip exits with status 12

Tags: unix, makefile, zip

`make` is halting and reporting an error code of 12 after attempting to `zip -u` some files.

The error code 12 is actually an exit status from zip which indicates that it has "nothing to do."

I don't understand why this is a non-zero exit status.  Wouldn't it be more appropriate to just let zip quietly do nothing?  It doesn't seem like an actual problem if zip has nothing to do.

I could suppress it: tell `make` to ignore non-zero exit status from zip by calling `-zip -u`.  But the problem with that approach is that 12 is the only exit status I want to ignore.  All of the others indicate actual problems that would cause me to want to abort `make`.

Maybe I could set a variable equal to the output from `echo $?` and then test for 0 or 12 but it seems klodgy to do this after every single `zip` statement in the .mk file.

Is there an elegant way to handle this?

Comment: Nothing more elegant than you've already thought of.  You can either ignore the error altogether, or check for the specific ones that you feel are not real errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Err... As a quick and dirty solution, you can use a shell wrapper:

```
#!/bin/ksh

zip "$@"
rc=$?

if [[ rc -eq 12 ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

exit $rc
```

Alternatively, you can do *almost* the same inline in Makefile but it will look somewhat ugly (will have to be a shell one-liner with duplicate `$` signs etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this sounds simpler to me.
It returns an error in make if the error code is non-zero and different of 12.

```
target:
    zip -uj file.zip file.csv || [ $$? -eq 12 ]
```